# Django: what is the difference between using request and context as argument

Tags: django

I am defining a function in my context_processor to pass a value from my settings to use in templates. So what is the right way, and more importantly what is the difference?

```
def baseurl(request):
    return {'BASE_URL': settings.BASE_URL}
```

or

```
def baseurl(context):
    return {'BASE_URL': settings.BASE_URL}
```

I have always used the first, but have run into a few examples of the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to call this argument whatever you like but `request` is the most common or clear. From the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

> A context processor has a very simple interface: It's just a Python function that takes one argument, an HttpRequest object, and returns a dictionary that gets added to the template context.

While there is nothing stopping you from naming this argument `context` it would be misleading since it is passed an HttpRequest object.

Comment: Not exactly true. If Django were to call `baseurl(request=request)` then obviously changing argument name would fail. Of course it's not the case, but still worth mentioning.

Comment: Yes if Django were to call it that way...which it doesn't so it is true as stated.

Answer (score 2):

From *django/template/context.py*:

```
class RequestContext(Context):
    """
    This subclass of template.Context automatically populates itself using
    the processors defined in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.
    Additional processors can be specified as a list of callables
    using the "processors" keyword argument.
    """
    def __init__(self, request, dict_=None, processors=None, current_app=None,
            use_l10n=None, use_tz=None):
        Context.__init__(self, dict_, current_app=current_app,
                use_l10n=use_l10n, use_tz=use_tz)
        if processors is None:
            processors = ()
        else:
            processors = tuple(processors)
        for processor in get_standard_processors() + processors:
            self.update(processor(request))
```

The last two lines are the most important. It means that arguments are not named. Thus it doesn't matter how you name your argument.